# Jakeday Kernel invokes the grub menu at startup

Tags: 18.04, grub2, surface

I am Linux beginner using SP3 with Ubuntu 18.04 and I tried installing the Jakeday kernel and it shows the grub menu each time on startup.  This also happened when I wasn running 19.04.  I followed his instructions command by command but unsure why this is coming up.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Refer to this tutorial from the repository itself → https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface/blob/master/SIGNING.md

Comment: @Jim That's exactly what I've followed.

Comment: Then I'm out of idea, can you [open new issues on their GitHub page ?](https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface/issues/new)